# Read over 13.000 txt files into RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying to load txt files into R. The files are EEG recordings for emotional words. Every text file is the recording of a word for a study participant. For every participant there are 360 words, which were recorded.
Every text file includes the complete time frame of EEG recording as a row (from 0 to 2000ms) and the electrodes from 1 to 58 in the column.

I have a Script for R worked out with a statistics crack, who is currently unavailable for me to ask again. The script used to work and read the data and produce and output.

Now RStudio does run the script to a certain point, but the RStudio environment does remain with every table showing NA for each data point. (Which it was able to read before.)

Much later R gives an error as output, but I guess this is mainly dependent on the data not being properly read. 
I seem to be blind to mistakes in the script, in which I did not change anything after it worked for the first time.

Also installing R on another computer for the first time and running the script results in the same output: The environment shows NA for all data. 
I have looked into several tips on how to read txt files into R, but they are not covering complex data. 
The employed code, to sum up the data into means per electrode and time point is as follows:

```
stats<-function(x,tf1=NA,tf2=NA){ 

natf1<-sum(is.na(tf1))>0
natf2<-sum(is.na(tf2))>0

if(natf1&natf2){tf1<-1:dim(x)[2]}

if(!natf1){
mx<-as.numeric(lapply(as.data.frame(t(x[,tf1])),max))
mn<-as.numeric(lapply(as.data.frame(t(x[,tf1])),mean))
min<-as.numeric(lapply(as.data.frame(t(x[,tf1])),min))
}

if(!natf2){
mx2<-as.numeric(lapply(as.data.frame(t(x[,tf2])),max))
mn2<-as.numeric(lapply(as.data.frame(t(x[,tf2])),mean))
min2<-as.numeric(lapply(as.data.frame(t(x[,tf2])),min))
}

if(natf2){
return(cbind(electrode=1:58,max1=mx,mean1=mn,min1=min
           ,max2=NA,mean2=NA,min2=NA))
}else{
return(cbind(electrode=1:58
             ,max1=mx,mean1=mn,min1=min
             ,max2=mx2,mean2=mn2,min2=min2))
}}
```

I hope somebody can help me and improve my limited knowledge. 
Cheers, Emily

P.S.: code to read the txt.files should be the following:

```
filenames<-dir() # dateinamen auslesen
nfiles<-length(filenames) #anzahl files

store<-matrix(rep(NA,nfiles*9*58),nfiles*58,9) 


ti<-2010/503
t250<-floor(250/ti)
t350<-ceiling(350/ti)
t350p1<-t350+1
t450<-ceiling(450/ti)

for(i in 1:nfiles){ 

data<-read.table(filenames[i], sep=" ",dec=".")
vp<-as.numeric(substr(filenames[i],3,4))    
word<-as.numeric(substr(filenames[i],15,17))   
print(i) 

store[(1+(i-1)*58):(58+(i-1)*58),1]<-rep(vp,58)  
store[(1+(i-1)*58):(58+(i-1)*58),2]<-word
store[(1+(i-1)*58):(58+(i-1)*58),3:9]<-stats(data,t250:t350,t350p1:t450)
}
```

data looks as follows (being the output of an EEG recording, that is listed by time(x) and electrode (y): 
-24.0726 -25.4886 -19.3321 -12.9210 -5.1501 3.1598 7.3684 4.7018 -2.2902 -7.5973 -8.6344 -7.8640 -7.4511 -6.1870 -2.6582 0.8325 1.3330 -0.3912 -1.8508 -3.5361 -5.7567 -6.1500 -5.9328 -6.0740 -5.1535 -3.7834 -0.3229 3.5887 2.1871 -3.7773 -7.5377 -7.9027 -10.2698 -11.9537 -8.7184 -6.0458 -9.0905 -14.2111 -17.0484 -18.7480 -17.6947 -12.7817 -9.0529 -7.9332 -8.9464 -11.4776 -13.9951 -11.9900 -3.6849 -1.1153 -5.2907 -4.8818 -2.8731 -5.9760 -7.7751 -5.4999 -7.4731 -9.3200 ...

error message received: 
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 5 did not have 2 elements

but I am not sure how to fix this or where/ in which file to check for said error

Comment: Is it the importing or summation that doesn't work? Ie. How does the data look before you run the code you posted?

Comment: I think it must be the import that does not work. But because the environment does only show NA I am not certain about this. The later import of csv table does work. Before I export the data it is txt.file and it involves only numbers, which are positive or negative for each time frame per electrode.

Comment: @NEO asks: 

If you did not change anything in the script, it is probably the data. Would request you to share a data snippet and the code you use to read in the data. please share output of str(), when you run it on the dataframe.

The data you are reading, is it from a database or CSV?

Comment: The error means that there is an inconsistency (too many or too few variables) in line 5 in one of the files. After you get the error get the value of filenames[i]. The inconsistency should be in line 5 of this file.

Comment: I was aware, that the error meant that, but not how to fix it. But I cannot seem to get to the value of the filenames. `print` does not yield any results.

Comment: when you get the error, the value of "i" in your for loop should be the index of the file that produces the error. "filename[i]" should then print the name of that file.